# React Create Portal event listening

Tags: reactjs

So I am trying to migrate an existing Portal implementation from the old unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer to the new portal implementation.

I have an issue though, the relevant code has the following functionality:

```
unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer(
  this,
  this.props.children,
  this.portalElement,
  () => {
      if (this.props.isOpen) {
          this.props.onRender(this.portalElement, 
          this.getTargetElement());
      }
      callback(); //runs this.props.open() if the update ran open
   },
);
```

Some of the open/close logic could be simplified by wrapping the component to be rendered inside an object and the appropriate callbacks could be called from there. But it seems createPortal has no callback to allow you specify when a render has or hasn't taken place. Is there anyway to synchronously or asynchronously on a createPortal call has finished rendering?

Comment: Can you modify the component you render inside to portal to use componentDidMount ?

Comment: No, as it could be anything.